# Ubuntu not finding an executable in local user

Tags: ubuntu, path, mpi, root

I 'm a new user in linux and currently having problems in executing a file when I'm logged in my user. I downloaded, compiled and adapted the PATH to find an executable file that I run through a script. I carried this procedure as root and as my user, but the program works just when I'm logged as root. When I use the commands

```
echo $PATH
which swash.exe
which mpiexec
which mpicc
```

I got the same result in both users but the program still doesn't work in my user.

Please any help will be useful

Comment: It would help if you would provide more details.

Comment: Sorry but how can I provide more details?

Comment: For example, what error message do you get? Is the file readable and executable for your user? Are all intermediate directories in the executable path executable (a.k.a. traversable) for your user? What does `ldd swash.exe` show? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check if you have executing right on the file as a regular user?

```
stat --format '%a' <file>
```

If the file is owned by the root user, then the third number has to be 5 or 7 to run the file as a regular user.

If you want to be sure that the file is executable for ALL user, you can simply do it by:

```
chmod 777 /path/to/yourfile
```

It's a big security leak, so use it only for testing.

Comment: Hi dsdenes, thanks for your help. I checked and the result is 777, I have the full permission for my regular user...How can I detail my question? Which information I should provide?